# LXC Container not pining from host or network

Tags: networking, lxc

I recently started looking at LXC container for hosting tunnel service (IPv6 over IPv4 and IPv6 over IPv6).
On my Window 10 machine I have Ubuntu 18.04 VM and I set up a Ubuntu 18.04 LXC Container which can ping VM, Host Window machine and 8.8.8.8.

But When I ping my container from Windows Host or any other Network machine it does not respond and shows Response Time out.

Please let me know if need more information.

Thanks for any help in Advance!

More Information

Ubuntu VM iptables -t nat -L

[image]

LXC Container ip a s

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding bridged interface. On default configuration, network was using NAT to communicate. for allowing other network host to access the LXD/LXC containers bridged interface should be used.
This provides more in depth details https://youtu.be/a0dzCzpdUfw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the problem is that there is no route information to LXC container.

I think the information you give here is not sufficient.
You should show:

#### 1. the ip and  route table of the windows host .

#### 2. the ip and route talbe of the Ubuntu VM.

Then, I will give you the solution.